# Finding intersection of two functions in Python (Scipy, root finding)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, root

So I have to write a code to find the intersections between two gaussian functions G1 with the variables (x,0,1) and g2 (x,1,2). I have to find all intersections  within x(-5,5)
If i take a simpler formula with the code down below it works but like this it gives me errors.
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import root
    
def g(x):
    return [(1/((2 * np.pi * 1**2)**0.5) * np.exp( - ( x[0] - 0 )**2 / ( 2 * 1**2))), 
            (1/((2 * np.pi * 2**2)**0.5) * np.exp( - ( x[0] - 1 )**2 / ( 2 * 2**2)))]
    
sol = root(g,[2],method='hybr')
    
sol.x
```

Answer (score 2):

I changed to this and get `1.18` as solution.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import root

def g(x):
    return [(1/((2 * np.pi * 1**2)**0.5) * np.exp( - ( x[0] - 0 )**2 / ( 2 * 1**2)))- (1/((2 * np.pi * 2**2)**0.5) * np.exp( - ( x[0] - 1 )**2 / ( 2 * 2**2)))]

sol = root(g,[2.0],method='hybr')
sol.x
```

**EDIT**: The below allows for multiple starting points.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import root
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def g(x):
    return (1/((2 * np.pi * 1**2)**0.5) * np.exp( - ( x - 0 )**2 / ( 2 * 1**2)))- (1/((2 * np.pi * 2**2)**0.5) * np.exp( - ( x - 1 )**2 / ( 2 * 2**2)))

sol = root(g,[-2.0,2],method='hybr')
sol.x
```

Comment: That seems to work, thank you! although it only finds one intersection...

Comment: If you run with `root(g,[-2.0],method='hybr')`, you get the second intersection. I'm not very familiar with `root()` so not sure how you would run it with two different starting points and get two answers.

Comment: See my edit for multiple starting points.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks alot!